# Findinf child element in Protractor

Tags: protractor

How to get child element of parent element?
I tried this way:

```
  var parent =element(by.xpath('somexpath'))
   var child = parent.element(by.xpath('//h4')) // There are multiple h4 elements in page 
   child.getText().then(function(t){
            console.log(t);
            callback();
       })
```

After running I am getting following message and getText() returning text of first //h4 tag in page not child //h4 element of parent element

[18:29:04] W/element - more than one element found for locator By(xpath, //h4) - the first result will be used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You miss '.' ahead '//h4'.

`//h4` means found h4 around the whole page

`.//h4` means found h4 under/start from current node, not whole page

```
var parent =element(by.xpath('somexpath'))

var child = parent.element(by.xpath('.//h4')) 
// There are multiple h4 elements in page 
child.getText().then(function(t){
   console.log(t);
   callback();
})
```